# Is there a way to call an iterator inside an iterator in Accumulo?

Tags: java, accumulo

I have two iterators applied on two tables and want the result to be available to a third iterator for further processing.

Basically what I am trying to perform is a join query across two tables server-side.

The first two iterators are filtering out some rows from Accumulo (Based on a criteria) and the third iterator is trying to perform a Join Query on the resultset.

Comment: Need more info. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What more info can I provide?  I would he happy to do so.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. There is no mechanism to do a single server side operation against two different tables. Furthermore, there is no mechanism to do a single service side operation against two different tablets. If you need to access two different 'datasets' in a single iterator, you must colocate them in such a way that related tablets are one in the same.

This is covered with one strategy of having source tables and then combined indexes, which would satisfy that purpose.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on source tables and combined indexes you mentioned in your answer. I am beginner on Accumulo so it would help me a lot if you could provide a brief overview of them. Thanks for answering.

Comment: This would be a manual process. It comes with the territory of the architecture - it's a datastore, not a database, so you need to come up with your own indexing strategy.

In your case, if you have 2 tables you're joining, you may want to consider creating a third table optimized for the query you're trying to do.